# EPERM error writing to file in node.js

Tags: node.js, permissions, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to update the GPIOs on my RaspberryPi by writing to the `/sys/class/gpio` folder and it's subfolders and files.

When I run the command

```
fs.readFileSync('/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value', 'utf-8');
```

I get the correct response, no problem.

When I run

```
fs.writeFileSync('/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value',0);
```

I get an EPERM error, which if I understand correctly, is telling me that I don't have the correct permissions to write to that file.

When I list the permissions on that file, I see that both root and the gpio group have read and write permissions, and my current user 'pi' is part of the gpio group. So everything should be fine.

If I run sudo node, I should have permission, but I still get the EPERM error.

It also appears to me that '/sys/class/gpio' is a virtual path to '/sys/devices/gpio', looking at the permissions on that folder, the gpio group has permissions there too, and of course, so does root.

Is this something specific to GPIO? I see a few node modules that enable gpio control via fs.writeFile, for example, https://github.com/EnotionZ/GpiO/blob/master/lib/gpio.js which writes directly to the same directory.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

I'm currently having the same issue, except with a BeagleBone Black.  Even if I execute my script as root, I get the error.  However, _if I run the script again_, it works with no errors.